# Codeigniter decrypt data before view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I have an codeigniter app and all data in database is coded using encrypt library.

Currently, I decrypt data in view page, but if you have 3000 results that you should return on a data table, page is very slow.

Is there any way to decrypt the data in controller ? and on the view to get directly decoded data ?

Comment: why not use a limit query, the data displayed is only 10 or 15 rows per page. I think there will be a difference, even your data is more than 3000

Comment: if you use a data table plugin, you can see the reference here https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: it doesn't work. because same info I retrieve on dropdowns. For e.g when I retrieve customers from db, I have a select dropdown with 3000 entries that should be decrypted.

Comment: use  select2  with  Ajax (remote data) for retrive on dropdowns  https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax. It's a good idea to separate the data retrieval function between the data table and the dropdown, because the data is getting more and more

Comment: @Murosadatul Thank a lot for your advices. Problem solved now ! Really appreciated.

Comment: @Murosadatul For select2 ajax, I have an  issue. Because the string is encoded in db ( ZuxKYGZpoiuVN5Vt7xLmJM9C18qxtoq9S5 ) when I search on the select2 for TEST string, it will not find it.. any hint how to solve this ?

Comment: I've never done it, try visiting this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655190/best-way-to-search-encrypted-data-inside-mysql
or this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields, maybe it can provide inspiration